# Importing MonadPlus into my haskell program

Tags: haskell, import, package, typeclass

I want to use MonadPlus type class. I downloaded it via cabal install, and have verified that it has been installed in my ubuntu (via cabal list MonadPlus). I also learned from Hackage that this class is referred by: 
Control.Monad.Plus

Now, when I go to ghci, how do I import this type class into ghci?

For instance, I want to load this piece of code:

```
import Control.Monad.Plus
guard :: (MonadPlus m) => Bool -> m ()  
guard True = return ()  
guard False = mzero
```

But I got the response from ghci is: "Could not find module 'Control.Monad.Plus'"

How do I import this type class?

Thank you.

CoolSC

Comment: `MonadPlus` is in the `Control.Monad` module.

Comment: @4castle, there is actually a `monadplus` package with a `Control.Monad.Plus` module with some `MonadPlus` utilities.

Comment: @dfeuer Right, but it's not needed for the `MonadPlus` typeclass.

Comment: Do you have a Cabal sandbox in your current directory? Is cabal using a different version of GHC? Either would explain your problem.

Comment: @dfeuer Thank you. Indeed, I have been using different version of GHC. Now the problem is resolved.